# Can HowdyAI's Botkit listen for attachment contents?

Tags: botkit

Attempting to use [BotKit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit) to have a custom integration react to a 3rd party integration.  The 3rd party integration only communicates via replies as [attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments).

Is there a way to have the my custom integration 'hear' attachments? I haven't been able to locate this in the documentation if it does exist already.

Comment: I did find an issue related to this. https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/46
I'll see if that is functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was present in the [comments on the issue](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/46).

Essentially:

```
controller.on('bot_message', function(bot, message) {
    console.log('message.attachments: ' + message.attachments);
    var attachment = message.attachments[0];
    console.log('attachments.title: ' + attachment.title);
    console.log('attachments.text: ' + attachment.text);
});
```